# SQL - SELECT within SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table named 'sms_messages' with attributes (sender, receiver, content).

GOAL: I would like to query all distinct senders, with their corresponding total number messages.

The query would look like this:

```
 SELECT count(content) from sms_messages WHERE sender = (SELECT distinct(sender) FROM sms_messages)
```

Unfortunately, this query won't work because there are multiple unique senders. Probably this can be done if iteration is possible inside the query. Or maybe there's a hero out there, who can save me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your require query to get distinct sender would be:

select sender, count(1)
from sms_messages
group by sender

Comment: Thank you! You saved my day :)

Comment: Its my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

Classic use-case for a [GROUP-BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html):

```
select content, count(1)
from sms_messages
group by content.
```